# Is it correct to say "the color" when describing a multi-colored object?

Tags: grammatical-number

For instance, "the color of the watermelon is red and green", or should one say "the colors of the watermelon are red and green"?

Comment: In practice your example usage is perfectly common, but the odd pedant might prefer *the **colouring** of the watermelon* - precisely because of the apparent singular/plural clash that's bothering you (but which *doesn't* bother the average native Anglophone).

Answer (score 2):

> the color of the watermelon is red and green

Is technically incorrect, but widely accepted and understood. One could also say more simply

> The watermelon is colored red and green

or even just

> The watermelon is red and green

since those will be understood as colors.

> The watermelon is green.

could mean that it is unripe, rather than green in color.